# Creating a debouncer in RxJava2

Tags: android, rx-java, rx-java2

In RxJava1 you can create a debouncer this way

```
RxSearchView.queryTextChanges(searchView)
    .debounce(1, TimeUnit.SECONDS) // stream will go down after 1 second inactivity of user
    .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
    .subscribe(new Consumer<CharSequence>() {
        @Override
        public void accept(@NonNull CharSequence charSequence) throws Exception {
            // perform necessary operation with `charSequence`
        }
    });
```

According to [Wait until the user stops typing before executing a heavy search in searchview](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43034025/wait-until-the-user-stops-typing-before-executing-a-heavy-search-in-searchview)

But I can't figure out how to create it in RxJava2

[image]

Comment: RxJava 2 uses the `io.reactivex.Observable` as the type and `io.reactivex.functions.Consumer` for that `subscribe` overload. Please check that you have the right types with `queryTextChanges`.

Answer (score 0):

remove

```
import io.reactivex.functions.Consumer;
```

add

```
import java.util.function.Consumer;

RxSearchView.queryTextChanges(searchView)
    .debounce(1, TimeUnit.SECONDS) // stream will go down after 1 second inactivity of user
    .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
    .subscribe(result -> new Consumer<CharSequence>() {
                @Override
                public void accept(CharSequence charSequence) {
                    // use result
                }
            });
```

Comment: Is there a workaround because it says I need api 24 when I only have 19

Comment: RxJava does not work with java.util.function.* at all so this is definitely a wrong answer.